# In emacs, how do I find the length of an identifier (or of the kill ring)?

Tags: emacs, plsql, emacs24

PL/SQL is restricted to a 30-character identifier length. I'd like to find the size of the identifier under my cursor without counting manually. (Underscores are breaking the identifier by word, so a solution by word may not work. I'm using emacs 24.3.1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Move the cursor to the beginning of the identifier. Then use C-M-@ to select the whole identifier (a "balanced expression") and M-= to show the statistics of the region. (On my Windows machine, C-M-2 works in lieu of C-M-shift-2.)

Answer (score 0):

You found the answer (`M-=`) in 10 minutes -- good. Another thing that can help (no need to hit `M-=`):

Library [`modeline-posn.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/modeline-posn.el) shows the size of the active region in the mode line. See [Mode-Line Position](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLinePosition).